# Как создать словарь, с вложенным словарем и сортировкой по дате на Python (3.9.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, коллекции, словари

У меня есть список вывода логов биометрического контроля из текстового файла. Данные логи контроллера были отформатированы, и занесены как список. Данные значения уже до этого отсортированы, в список "заходит" первое событие, и последнее. В формате:

```
monitor_last_first = [
    ['Ваня', '8:33', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Ваня', '18:40', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '9:42', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '21:51', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '9:02', '02.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '18:51', '02.01.1995'],
    ['Женя', '10:01', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Женя', '20:51', '01.01.1995'],

]
```

Мне необходимо создать словарь, с вложенным словарем. Значения для данного словаря должны браться из данного списка, а именно имя, и дата. После чего сортироваться, дабы в итоговом словаре было имя того кто пришел/ушел, и все его приходы/уходы, с привязкой по дате. В формате:

```
monitor_dict = {
    {'Ваня': {'01.01.1995': ['08:33', '18:40']}},
    {'Петя': {'01.01.1995': ['09:42', '21:51']}, {'02.01.1995': ['09:02', '18:51']},
    ['Женя': {'01.01.1995': ['10:01', '20:51']},

}
```

Проект домашний, не учебный/рабочий. По этому определенный алгоритм решения не нужен. Скорость тоже не играет сути, будет это выполняться 5 мкс, или 10 секунд не особо важно, так как скрипт запускается раз в месяц. Буду очень благодарен за хотя-бы наводку по решению, уже гуглил довольно много, решения не нашел.

Comment: А может быть такое, что в один день человек будет входить-выходить несколько раз? Что в таком случае должно быть в списке, несколько пар значений?

Comment: В день у меня из сырцов событий около 10+ на одного человека (всего 5 человек), но я использую sqlite3 где отфильтровываю по первому, и последнему событию. Если происходит какая-то ошибка вроде есть вход, но нету выхода (такое бывает, входят по двое через дверь) то я делаю время выхода как 00:00 и заношу эти данные в список. 

В данном списке только первый "вход" и последний "выход", ничего больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение в одну строчку, если не считать импортов... :)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

monitor_dict = dict([person, dict([date, list(map(itemgetter(1), times))] for date, times in groupby(visits, itemgetter(2)))] for person, visits in groupby(monitor_last_first, itemgetter(0)))
```

Comment: Поставил +, т.к. решение рабочее, но в такое поддерживать и врагу не пожелаешь :D

Answer (score 3):

Нужно просто налету сгенерировать словарь из словарей, состоящих из списка:

```
monitor_last_first = [
    ['Ваня', '8:33', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Ваня', '18:40', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '9:42', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '21:51', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '9:02', '02.01.1995'],
    ['Петя', '18:51', '02.01.1995'],
    ['Женя', '10:01', '01.01.1995'],
    ['Женя', '20:51', '01.01.1995'],
]

monitor_dict = dict()
for name, time, date in monitor_last_first:
    if name not in monitor_dict:
        monitor_dict[name] = dict()

    if date not in monitor_dict[name]:
        monitor_dict[name][date] = []

    monitor_dict[name][date].append(time)
```

**Тот же код, что выше,** но через [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

...

monitor_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for name, time, date in monitor_last_first:
    monitor_dict[name][date].append(time)
```

Проверяем:

```
print(monitor_dict)

import json
print(json.dumps(monitor_dict, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Результат:

```
{'Ваня': {'01.01.1995': ['8:33', '18:40']}, 'Петя': {'01.01.1995': ['9:42', '21:51'], '02.01.1995': ['9:02', '18:51']}, 'Женя': {'01.01.1995': ['10:01', '20:51']}}
{
    "Ваня": {
        "01.01.1995": [
            "8:33",
            "18:40"
        ]
    },
    "Петя": {
        "01.01.1995": [
            "9:42",
            "21:51"
        ],
        "02.01.1995": [
            "9:02",
            "18:51"
        ]
    },
    "Женя": {
        "01.01.1995": [
            "10:01",
            "20:51"
        ]
    }
}
```

---

**PS.**

Если нужно, что время добавлялось с лидирующим 0, то можно добавить в цикл строку:

```
time = time.zfill(5)
```

Comment: Еще можно использовать collections.defaultdict(dict) - это позволит избежать проверки `if name not in monitor_dict`

Comment: @rvs, ага, и еще раз его внутри использовать как `defaultdict(list)` :) Не хотел перегружать код, но думаю действительно добавить пример с этим, спасибо